# Must a PyOMO's model objective function return a PyOMO Var object?

Tags: pyomo

I have an objective function in a model that returns a regular float which must be minimized.

But when I try to solve it I get the following Warning and the solver doesn't search for a solution:

```
WARNING: Constant objective detected, replacing with a placeholder to prevent
solver failure.
```

I also get a second Warning:

```
WARNING: Empty constraint block written in LP format - solver may error
```

Do I have to add contraints to the model? I already set bounds on the parameters to be optimized.

Comment: The evaluation of the OBJ must be dependent on the Variables.  Is it?

Any reason you didn't post the OBJ function and other code needed to get a better look at the issue, which would greatly increase the odds of getting a good answer?  :)

Comment: My objective function calls external code that do not know how to handle PyOMO Var values so I have have to convert them to plain values before evaluating the loss

Comment: A Pyomo objective function (and any objective function in mathematical programming) needs to be explicitly expressed with a mathematical expression. If now you are trying to optimize a metric that is returned by another function, perhaps a metaheuristic optimization algorithm (e.g. a Genetic Algorithm, Particle Swarm etc.) is the option that can be used.